# Как в postgresql при сортировке указать, начиная с какого элемента выводить данные?

Tags: sql, postgresql, сортировка

Как в postgresql при сортировке указать, начиная с какого элемента выводить данные?
К примеру, я сортирую по дате ORDER BY date, как указать, что выводить эти данные нужно начиная с определенной даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор [WHERE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-where/)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field > '2021-06-02'::date;
```